# Composition of a piecewise continuous function and a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be piecewise continuous and $g(x)$ continuous. What can be said about  $f(g(x))$? Is it piecewise continuous, does it have countable many discontinuities, does it have a left and right limit everywhere, etc., or none of the above?  I guess that it is not  piecewise continuous, but there should be some regularity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What definition of *piecewise continuous* are you working with? At most countably many discontinuities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, even if we define piecewise continuous in a rather restricted way (e.g., finitely many discontinuities), we can't really conclude very much about the discontinuities of the composition $f\circ g$ (though see update below).  In fact even a single discontinuity in $f$ can wreak havoc on our composition.  To see this, let
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x>0\text{,}\\
-1 & x<0\text{,}\\
0 & x=0\text{,}
\end{cases}
$$
let $C\subseteq \mathbb R$ be a Cantor set, let $U$ denote the union of the open intervals removed at the odd stages of the construction of $C$, and let $V$ be the union of the open intervals removed at the even stages.  Then define
$$
g(t)=
\begin{cases}
d(t,C) & t\in U\text{,}\\
-d(t,C) & t\in V\text{,}\\
0 & t\in C\text{.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g$ is clearly continuous (indeed it is even Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $1$), but the composition $f\circ g$ is discontinuous at every point in $C$, and there are only countably many points in $C$ where either the left hand limit or the right hand limit are defined (namely, the endpoints of the components of $U$ and $V$).

Since the Cantor set is uncountable, we are left with uncountably many discontinuities, and even uncountably many points with undefined left-hand and right-hand limits.

Note that this works for an arbitrary Cantor set, including a so-called "fat" Cantor set of positive measure, so we cannot even say that things only go bad on a set of measure $0$.

##### Update

There is one thing we can say, from a topological perspective.  If there are finitely many discontinuities for $f$ (or, more generally, if the set of discontinuities is nowhere dense), then the set of discontinuities of $f\circ g$ is nowhere dense.  To see this, observe that if $S$ is the set of discontinuities of $f$, and $x\notin g^{-1}(\bar{S})$ (which is closed), then $f\circ g$ is continuous at $x$, but also if $x$ is in the interior of $g^{-1}(\bar{S})$, then $f\circ g$ is constant near $x$, so $f\circ g$ is again continuous at $x$.  Thus the discontinuities can only lie in $\partial g^{-1}(\bar{S})$, which is nowhere dense.